# MS SQL datetime prior than 1/1/1900

Tags: sql-server, date

Surely there is a way to store a date value prior than 1-1-1900 in a column other than varchar? Or do I really have to break this out, and perform my own datetime library for date differences, sorting, and such?

Yes, I understand how datetime's are actually stored (an integer value from a specific date), but I remember there being another workaround from years ago. It's just slipping me now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

smalldatetime vs. datetime!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx

!

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had told the dev to make that change and they were still having the same problem. Then when I saw the msdn article, I asked them to refresh their connection and try again, sure enough, 'datetime' worked this time. (Or they had not applied the change originally).

Answer (score 3):

Yes the SQL Server DateTime type can store dates from 1 January 1753.

Comment: With the proviso that you're buggered if you want to do (for example) a genealogy app to record someone born in 1536.

Comment: To get a bigger range you can store an integer (of appropriate range) in the database and use something like "Unix time" to interpret it in your code

Comment: @JoelFan - yes you can store as an integer or string - or use datetime2 in SQL Server 2008 which has a bigger range.  But "Unix time" is a bad example as it only represents dates >= 01/01/1970.

Comment: @Joe, Not true!  Using *signed* integers you can represent any date in Unix time... negative is prior to 1/1/1970

Comment: @JoelFan, I think what Joe means is the interpretation of calendars etc. 1582 the Gregorian calendar was introduced. Before that time the Julian calendar was used. It's a mess back then and I suspect the date 1753 may also represent some calendar reform... just adding or subtracting time units will not necessarily result in correct dates that far back.

Comment: @erk, well, what he actually said that Unix time can only represent dates > 1/1/1970.  That is not correct because he's neglecting the fact that the value can be negative to represent dates < 1/1/1970. "The minimum representable date is Friday 1901-12-13, and the maximum representable date is Tuesday 2038-01-19"

Comment: @JoelFan, yes, back to 1901-12-13 you'd be safe from any calendar problems. OP wants support for dates before 1900. You need to use a bigint for that. I don't have an SQL-server up and running but an estimate tells me you could go back to Cro-Magnon-times... and if you provide the function you can be sure a user will provide the large enough (small enough?) value... That's why Unix time is problematic here.

Comment: @erk, 1753 just represented a more widespread adoption of the Gregorian Calendar (namely its adoption by the British Empire).  There were several centuries where both calendars were in use.  The change was very slow.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 has the DATE data type which can range from 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

With previous versions, your SOL if you need a date prior to 1753-01-01 (Minimum value for DATETIME).